# Python AppEngine; get user info and post parameters?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Im checking the examples google gives on how to start using python; especifically the code posted here; http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html

The thing that i want to lean is that, here:

```
class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    greeting = Greeting()

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

They are saving a comment, IF the user is logged in, we save the user; if not its empty and when we get it out of the db we actually check for that here:

```
  if greeting.author:
    self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
  else:
    self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
```

So what i would like is to use the User object to get the information, like this:

```
class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting = Greeting()
        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()
            greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
            greeting.put()
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

So, what i would like to do with that code is to send the user to the login url(if he is not logged in); and then to come back with whatever he had in post and actually post it. But what happens is that it doesnt even get to that action coz is nothing in the post. 
I know i could put something in the session and check for it in the get action of the guestbook, but i wanted to check if someone could come up with a better solution!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, `self.redirect` cannot "carry along" the payload of a `POST` HTTP request, so (from a `post` method) the redirection to the login-url &c is going to misbehave (in fact I believe the login URL will use `get` to continue when it's done, and that there's no way to ask it to do a `post` instead).

If you don't want to stash that `POST` payload around somewhere (session or otherwise), you can make your code work by changing the `def post` in your snippet above to `def get`, and of course the `action="post"` in the HTML written in other parts of the example that you haven't snipped to `action="get"`. There are other minor workarounds (you could accept `post` for "normal" messages from logged-in users and redirect them to the `get` that perhaps does something simpler if they weren't logged in yet), but I think this info is sufficient to help you continue from here, right?

Comment: There's several rather large caveats to this solution: GETs are a poor choice for long data, and they're intended to be idempotent. Submitting anything non-idempotent (such as a guestbook entry) introduces XSRF issues.

Comment: @Nick, good points -- that's why a "stash payload around somewhere" approach is also worth considering (e.g., whenever the data may be long, or if potential forgeries are an issue despite the "logged-in user" condition on the GET being accepted).